# Unity Remove Asset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to unload assets after adding them to an array of objects, but it's returning an error saying I can only remove one at a time but I'm not sure how to do that

```
object[] tempItems = Resources.LoadAll("Inventory/Weapons");
foreach (object i in tempItems)
{
    GameObject it = (GameObject)i;
    Debug.Log(it);
    itemList.Add(it);
    Debug.Log(itemList.Count);
}


foreach (object i in tempItems)
{
    GameObject it = (GameObject)i;
    Resources.UnloadAsset(it);
}
```

`UnloadAsset` may only be used on individual assets and can not be used on GameObject's / Components or AssetBundles

Im now using

```
    UnityEngine.Object[] tempItems = Resources.LoadAll("Inventory/Weapons");
    foreach (UnityEngine.Object i in tempItems)
    {
        GameObject it = (GameObject)i;
        Debug.Log(it);
        itemList.Add(it);
        Debug.Log(itemList.Count);
    }
    foreach (UnityEngine.Object i in tempItems)
    {
        Resources.UnloadAsset(i);
    }
```

But im still getting the error

```
UnloadAsset may only be used on individual assets and can not be used on GameObject's / Components or AssetBundles
```

this is the line of the error

```
        Resources.UnloadAsset(i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unload the `Object` not `GameObject`. The casting `GameObject it = (GameObject)i;Resources.UnloadAsset(it);` is totally unnecessary and likely the problem.

```
Object[] tempItems = Resources.LoadAll("Inventory/Weapons",typeof(GameObject));
foreach (Object i in tempItems)
{
    GameObject it = (GameObject)i;
    Debug.Log(it);
    itemList.Add(it);
    Debug.Log(itemList.Count);
}

foreach (Object i in tempItems)
{
    Resources.UnloadAsset(i);
}
```

I also suggest you use Object with capitalized 'O'. Don't think it will make a difference but just in-case.

Comment: Using object with a capital o returns a compatibility error, also using unloadAsset as suggested returns the same error

Comment: Object' is an ambiguous reference between `UnityEngine.Object' and `object'

Comment: @Sniffle6 Modified my answer. Look at it again. If there is an error write down the line of code you are getting the error from.

Comment: i Used UnityEngine.Object and it doesnt return the ambiguous error but i still get the UnloadAsset may only be used on individual assets and can not be used on GameObject's / Components or AssetBundles when i use unload

Comment: Updated the original question with the new code/error

Comment: @Sniffle6 Modified my answer. I added `typeof(GameObject)`. Just copy and paste it then let me know what happens.

Comment: SAme error
UnloadAsset may only be used on individual assets and can not be used on GameObject's / Components or AssetBundles
UnityEngine.Resources:UnloadAsset(Object)
UIManager:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/UIManager.cs:33)

Comment: Do you think it has anyhting to do with the fact i have to use UnityEngine.Object instead of just Object. im using the import "using UnityEngine" so im confused as too why i have to do the UnityEngine.Object int he first place

Comment: I even tried just using 

           Resources.UnloadAsset(tempItems[0]);
but i still get the same error

Comment: @Sniffle6 I just tried it and that's a bug in Unity. Don't use `Resources.UnloadAsset`. Simply put `Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();` in the `OnDisable()` function.

Comment: Yeah thats what i ended up doing :) I think i also found out why it was actually not working, but the unusedAsset works fine i suppose

Comment: @Sniffle6 Good. You said you think i also found out  it was not working. Can you share with me? I just think it is a bug. Maybe your findings will shed some light on this

Comment: Well after further thinking about what the error said, it says i cant use GameObject's  and i was :D so i guess that would be why lolll

That or, since im loading the resource into a list of gameObjects, maybe it still considers it being used

Comment: @Sniffle6 Ok. I also read that this error only occur in the Editor but not in a standalone build. I don't believe this. Anyways happy coding